# Retrieving a user's name with only one request to Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Right now I'm working on a project that stores a user's name and user id in a database and I'm using the Facebook javascript SDK. Is there any way to retrieve both with just one request?

Currently I'm sending a login request to facebook which gives me an access token with the user id and making a second request to the Graph API, but sending two requests seems wasteful when the only thing I need from the second request is the name.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.authResponse) {
  FB.api('/me', function (resp) {
    console.log(resp);
      dbUtils.findOrCreateUser(response.authResponse.userID.toString(),resp.name, response);
  }); 
  } else { 
    AppActions.notLoggedIn(); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response object is fixed; you cannot request additional information with the getLoginStatus() query. There are a number of reasons for this design, but I think the most straightforward motivation is separation of responsibility. *The login flow is for logins and the Graph API is for the graph!*

Fortunately, getLoginStatus() might not actually be hitting the FB server with every call. Check the "Roundtrips to Facebook's servers" on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

And since you'll have the user's name in your database, you can just skip the graph call for that user's name in the future. So ultimately, I think it is not too big of an overhead.

Comment: Thanks Toby, that makes sense. I didn't even think about only needing to check the name the first time a user is created.